# Appropriate graph representation for network flow algorithms

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, max-flow

When implementing [Ford-Fulkerson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ford%E2%80%93Fulkerson_algorithm) or [Dinitz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinic%27s_algorithm) algorithms for maximum network flow there are two operations that need to be performed on the graph:

- Iterate over all neighbours of a given vertex
- Find the reverse edge of a given edge(this is needed for the graph modification when a flow is added along an augmenting path).

Ideally the first operation will be linear with respect to the number of neighbours and the second one should be constant. In addition the memory required for the graph representation should be linear with respect to the number of edges(note that for most practical applications of max network flow algorithms I have seen the number of edges is about linear times the number of vertices). All the estimations for the complexity for the two algorithms will only hold if the constraints above are met.

The problem is that none of the classical graph representations is able to meet the above requirements:

### Adjacency Matrix

Using adjacency matrix, finding the reverse edge of a given edge can be done in constant time. However iterating over all neighbours is linear with respect to the number of **all vertices** and also the required memory is quadratic with respect to the number of vertices.

### Edges list

Using this representation, iterating over all neighbours will not be linear with respect to the number of neighbours and also finding the reverse edge for a given edge is not constant.

### Neighbours list

Using this representation we can iterate over all neighbours in linear time and also the needed memory is linear with respect to the number of edges. Still, finding the reverse edge for a given edge will be linear with respect to the number of neighbours of the destination vertex.

With a slight modification of this representation we could improve that - if instead of neighbours list we keep some binary search tree of the neighbours we could find the reverse edge with logarithmic complexity. And even better - if we use hash map instead of binary search tree we will have constant amortized complexity. Still this representation does not feel right - although still linear, a hash map has some memory overhead. Also it only has amortized constant complexity thus some operations may in fact be slower.

### The question

So my question is: what graph representation is appropriate to implement maximum network flow algorithms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would describe Ivaylo's representation as "edge-contiguous". There's also an "endpoint-contiguous" representation, which I believe from an extremely unscientific sample to be in wider use. I have implemented both at various times.

Absent hard data, my hypothesis would be that the endpoint-contiguous representation is better for the usual suspects network flow algorithms than the edge-contiguous representation, since edge-contiguous incurs a random access each time an arc is scanned, and endpoint-contiguous, each time flow is pushed on an arc (which presumably was preceded by scanning the arc). The clear upside of this representation is that it supports unsymmetric graphs (not so relevant for network flow). The clear downside of this representation is that changing the topology of the graph is much slower.

The representation consists of two arrays. `first`, with n+1 elements, stores the index of the first arc with the specified tail. The extra entry is m, the total number of arcs, so that the indexes of arcs with tail v are `first[v]` inclusive through `first[v+1]` exclusive. On Ivaylo's graph,

```
[0] = 0->1, [1] = 0->2,
[2] = 1->0, [3] = 1->2, [4] = 1->3,
[5] = 2->0, [6] = 2->1, [7] = 2->3, [8] = 2->4,
[9] = 3->1, [10] = 3->2, [11] = 3->5,
[12] = 4->2, [13] = 4->5,
[14] = 5->3, [15] = 5->4,
```

the array `first` is

```
0, 2, 5, 9, 12, 14, 16.
```

The arcs themselves are stored in an m-element array of the following structure type.

```
struct Arc {
    int head;
    int capacity;
    int symmetric;
};
```

`symmetric` is the index of the symmetric arc.

Comment: Why are you storing the reverse edges next to each other? I mean I see how I can modify your code to store the straight edges in adjacent memory cells, but is there a reason why you do it this way?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev The arcs are to be stored in the order `0->1, 0->2, 1->0, 1->2, ...` etc. I fixed a couple typos and added element indexes.

Comment: This is how hi_pr and all the other open-source solvers do it. I'm currently working on parallel max-flow and this is by far the most efficient representation that I tested for static graphs, for whatever that is worth. It also helps to store the reverse residual capacity or the original edge capacity along with the residual capacity, so that you can do a reverse BFS without cache misses due to reverse edge lookups (for example during the global relabling phase of Push-Relabel)

Answer (score 2):

The representation I use is somewhat a mixture between edges list and neighbours list. It has no official name that I know of so I will not name it. It manages to meet all the requirements above and requires only using arrays - a structure that is present in most(if not all) popular programming languages. I will be using `c++` for the illustration but the code should be easily translatable to other languages. For this answer I will assume the vertices are numbered `0` to `N-1` and that our graph has `M` edges.

The graph that we store will be directed as when dealing with network flows usually the edge and its reverse edge have different capacities(and these capacities sum up to the initial capacity of the edge).

### An edge

As we are dealing with network flow algorithms each edge will have capacity(`cap`). In addition for each edge I will store its destination vertex(`to`) and another value that I will call `next`. We can also optionally add a source vertex, but it is not required because of the way the graph will be represented. I will assume all these values fit into an `int` type:

```
struct edge {
  // destination vertex
  int to;
  // capacity
  int cap;
  // next edge
  int next;
};
```

### Storing the graph

I will store all edges in an array and in addition I will have one more array where I store "head" elements for the neighbours list of each vertex. I will name the array with the "head" elements `first`. `first` should be initialized with some value that is not a valid vertex number e.g. -1:

```
int first[N];
// in c++ we can also use memset
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
  first[i] = -1;
}
```

Because of the way max network flow algorithms are implemented, for each edge we should add a reverse edge with 0 capacity. For that reason the size of the array where we store the edges is in fact `2*M`:

```
edge edges[M * 2];
```

Now there are two key things to the representation I suggest:

1. We form a (single)linked list of the neighbours of a given vertex and the index of the head(first) element of each linked list is stored in the array `first`.
2. For each edge we add its reverse edge right after it in the array of edges

Adding an element to a single linked list so there is only a small caveat in the `add_edge` function - we should also add the reverse edge. To simplify the code I will assume that we have a variable `edges_num` that represents the number of edges we have already added and I will use it as if it is a global variable. I implement an `add_edge` function that takes three arguments - the source vertex, the destination vertex and the capacity of the edge:

```
int edges_num = 0;
inline void add_edge(int from, int to, int cap) {
  edges[edges_num].to = to;
  edges[edges_num].cap = cap;
  edges[edges_num].next = first[from];
  first[from] = edges_num++;

  edges[edges_num].to = from;
  edges[edges_num].cap = 0;
  edges[edges_num].next = first[to];
  first[to] = edges_num++;
}
```

Note that the capacity of the reverse edge is `0` as this is usually the way it is initialized. That is pretty much all we need to store the graph using this representation.

### An example

[image]

Let's see how the contents of the two arrays `first` and `edges` will changes:

Before adding any edge:

```
first:                edges:
 0  1  2  3  4  5     []
-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

Let's add the edge 0 -> 2 with capacity 7. I will separate the two steps - adding the straight and the reverse edge:

```
first:                edges:
 0  1  2  3  4  5     [{to: 2, cap: 7, next: -1}]
 0 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
```

And now the reverse edge:

```
first:                edges:
 0  1  2  3  4  5     [{to: 2, cap: 7, next: -1}, {to: 0, cap: 0, next: -1}]
 0 -1  1 -1 -1 -1
```

And now let's add 0->1 (capacity 5):

```
first:                edges:
 0  1  2  3  4  5     [{2, 7, -1}, {0, 0, -1}, {1, 5, 0}, {0, 0, -1}]
 2 -1  1 -1 -1 -1
```

Note that the edge with index 2 has a next value of 0 indicating that 0 is the next edge that has source 0. I will continue adding edges:

2->1 capacity 1:

```
first:                edges:
 0  1  2  3  4  5     [{2, 7, -1}, {0, 0, -1}, {1, 5, 0}, {0, 0, -1}, {1, 1, 1},
 2  5  4 -1 -1 -1      {2, 0, -1}]
```

And now fast forward adding 2->3(capacity 11), 2->4(capacity 8), 1->3(capacity 4), 4->5(capacity 3) and 3->5(capacity 6) in the same order:

```
first:                edges:
 0  1  2  3  4  5     [{2, 7, -1}, {0, 0, -1}, {1, 5, 0}, {0, 0, -1}, {1, 1, 1},
 2 10  8 14 12 15      {2, 0, -1}, {3, 11, 4}, {2, 0, -1}, {4, 8, 6}, {2, 0, -1},
                       {3, 4, 5}, {1, 0, 7}, {5, 3, 9}, {4, 0, -1}, {5, 6, 11}, 
                       {3, 0, 13}]
```

Hope this example makes it clear how the representation works.

### Iterating over all neighbours

The iteration over all neighbours of a given vertex v is simple - just an iteration over a single linked list:

```
for (int cv = first[v]; cv != -1; cv = edges[cv].next) {
   // do something
}
```

It is apparent that this operation is linear over the number of neighbours.

### Accessing the reverse edge

Using the fact that the reverse edge is always added right after the straight one, the formula for the index of the reverse edge is really simple. The reverse edge of edge with index `e` in `edges` is the edge with index `e ^ 1`. This works for both accessing the reverse of a straight edge and the reverse of a reverse edge. Again this is apparently constant and very easy to code.

### Memory consumption

The required memory is `O(M + N)` - we have `edges` that is of size `M*2` and `first` that is of size `N`. Of course `N < M` for any sensible graph so the overall memory complexity is `O(M)`. Also the memory consumption will be much(at least twice) less than the memory consumption of the solution that uses hash maps for the neighbours list.

### Summary

This graph representation implements all the required operations with the best possible complexity and also it has little memory overhead. An addition advantage of the representation is that it only uses a very basic structure that is built-in in most languages - the array. This structure may be used for other algorithms too, but the fast access to the reverse edge is particularly useful for graph algorithms.

Comment: I don't know the formal name for this representation, but I would describe it as the edge-contiguous adjacency list rep. I'm fond of it for dynamic graphs, but for network flow, I would tend to believe that the head- or tail-contiguous counterpart is friendlier to the cache.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat what do you mean by `head- or tail-contiguous counterpart`. Maybe you would add this approach as an alternative answer?

Comment: Reminds me of [e-maxx](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/dinic) :) I believe the idea here is minimal amount of code, rather than memory efficiency, because it incurs lots of cache misses in the tight loops (BFS/DFS neighbor scans or admissible arc search in Push-Relabel)